# Prove that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}dx$ diverges.

Tags: integration, analysis

Def: $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx:= \lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int_1^b f(x)dx$.

Motivation: Just a routine homework problem to check the student's understanding of comparison tests for convergence of improper integrals.

I gave my own answer below.

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sin%5E2(x)%2Fx+dx+from+0+to+infty), it diverges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

$$\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$$

with

$$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(2x)}{2x}dx$$ convergent by Dirichlet' test and

$$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{2x}$$
divergent.
the sum is divergent near $+\infty$.

Comment: @ZKane it does not decompose into two divergent improper integrals. The integral of cos(2x)/2x is convergent!

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Ok, thank you. I need to learn about Dirichlet's test for improper integrals. Do you happen to know where a proof of this result can be found?

Comment: @ZKane Sorry, no. But stackexchange or google could help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\sin^2(x)$ is large when $x = k \pi + \frac\pi 2$, which implies that the integral majorates the harmonic series.

Centered at every number of the form $x_k = k \pi + \frac\pi 2$, we can find an interval $I_{k}$ of size $2\delta$ (independent of $k$) such that $\sin^2(x) \geq 0.99$ for $x \in I_k$.

Then $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}x \geq \delta \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{0.99}{k \pi + \frac{\pi}2} = \infty$$

Comment: (+1) Same idea but maybe easier, as it is more concrete: $\sin^2 x\ge 1/2$ for $x\in [\pi/4 +k\pi, 3\pi/4 + k\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

I think of an elementary way to show the crucial convergence of $\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x}dx$ without referring to the Dirichlet's test (although the idea is similar, i.e., integration by parts).

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{t}dt=\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\bigg|_{2}^\infty+\int_{2}^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t^2}dt$$

And the first term on the right is finite since

$$0\leq \bigg|\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\bigg|\leq\bigg|\frac{1}{t}\bigg|\rightarrow0 \text{ as t }\rightarrow\infty  $$

And the second term on the right converges for a similar reason

$$\bigg|\frac{\sin(t)}{t^2}\bigg|\leq\bigg|\frac{1}{t^2}\bigg|\quad\Rightarrow\quad \int_2^\infty \bigg|\frac{\sin(t)}{t^2}\bigg|dt\leq\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{t^2}dt=\frac{1}{2}$$